# What explainer video creation software is out there for OSX?

Tags: osx, video-editing

I need to purchase explainer video creation SOFTWARE. Could someone list the explainer video creation software currently on the market by ease of use?

*online services need not apply.

Comment: I think there is very few explainer videos software that runs offline on Mac or on OSX. But there are many software there which run online (Means they run online on web browser so you can access from OSX Browser) If you are unable to find the best software for explainer video then you can order your explainer video from [Explainer Video Production Company](https://2dvideoexpert.com/). They will make your video and deliver it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Keynote](https://itunes.apple.com/app/keynote/id409183694?mt=12&at=10lvzo&ct=ExplainerVideo) and [iMovie](https://itunes.apple.com/app/imovie/id408981434?mt=12&at=10lvzo&ct=ExplainerVideo) to create [my latest explainer video](https://youtu.be/bNtyBKxdCVY).  Keynote was used to create the bulk of the animation and export the presentation out to a movie file. Then iMovie was used to add in some background music and the voice-over track from a voice actor I hired from Fiver.